# Weird numbers and letters at the end of sections in a newspaper

Tags: united-states, historiography

At the end of each section in this newspaper (http://fultonhistory.com/Newspaper%2018/New%20York%20NY%20Morning%20Courier/New%20York%20NY%20Morning%20Courier%201852/New%20York%20NY%20Morning%20Courier%201852%20-%200482.pdf) are weird numbers and/or letters.  For example, at the end of the

> ADRIAN H. MULLER Auctioneer.
>
> PEREMPTORY SALE OF 250 VALUABLE LOTS OF

section there is the line

> 1623,26,28. M1, 4, 8, 9, 10      (1168)

And at the end of the section directly above it, there is the line

> (1859) mh8 10 ts

What do these lines mean?

Comment: As a guess, it looks as if these are internal classification codes used by the newspaper to identify the advert (perhaps the different types of goods and services offered, while the 'mhX' style codes appear in many ads and could be a code for the lot's location in the city).

Comment: While certainly fascinating to students of lithography and printing, this is not a question of significant historical importance.